# Need some SQL Stored proc help - joining

Tags: t-sql

So I have this section of my proc:

```
SELECT
        com_contact.rc_name_full as CreatedBy,
        capComponent.cm_strike as CapStrike,
        floorComponent.cm_strike as FloorStrike,
        tq_nominal_notional as Notional,
        maxComponent.cm_effective_dt as EffectiveDate,
        maxComponent.cm_maturity_dt as MaturityDate,
        CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(mm,maxComponent.cm_effective_dt,maxComponent.cm_maturity_dt) as decimal(9,2))/12 as decimal(9,2)) as term,
        (
            CASE WHEN se_amort_term_mnth IS NOT NULL THEN se_amort_term_mnth / 12
            ELSE CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(mm,
                ISNULL(cmam_amortization_start_dt, maxComponent.cm_effective_dt),
                cmam_amortization_end_dt) as decimal(9,2))/12 as decimal(9,2))
            END
        ) AS AmortTermYears,
        tq_dd_product as Product,
        dh_key_rate as KeyRate,
        dh_pv01 as PV01,
        dh_val_time_stamp as RateTimeStamp,
        re_bnk_le.re_company_name as Company,
        rc_contact_id as UserId,
        stp_name as NickName,
        '' as project,
        '' as Borrower,
        '' as Lender,
        '' as AdditionalInfo,
        CASE WHEN tpm_pd_permission_id = 85 THEN 'LLH' WHEN tpm_pd_permission_id = 86 THEN 'ALM' ELSE '' END as Permission,
        tr_transaction_id as TransactionId,
        NULL as IndicationId

    FROM cfo_transaction
```

The line that says `'' as project`, we have to actually change to return data now.

The table that next to the `FROM`, called `cfo_transaction` has an id on it called `tr_transaction_id`. We have another table called `com_project_transaction_link`, that links those id's with project id's, using two two columns called:

`pt_tr_transaction_id` and `pt_pj_project_id`, and then we have a table containing all the projects called `com_project` that has a `pj_project_id` and a `pj_project_name`.

GOAL: return the `pj_project_name` from that projects table where it links with the transactions being pulled.

I really don't know how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
        com_contact.rc_name_full as CreatedBy,
        capComponent.cm_strike as CapStrike,
        floorComponent.cm_strike as FloorStrike,
        tq_nominal_notional as Notional,
        maxComponent.cm_effective_dt as EffectiveDate,
        maxComponent.cm_maturity_dt as MaturityDate,
        CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(mm,maxComponent.cm_effective_dt,maxComponent.cm_maturity_dt) as decimal(9,2))/12 as decimal(9,2)) as term,
        (
            CASE WHEN se_amort_term_mnth IS NOT NULL THEN se_amort_term_mnth / 12
            ELSE CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(mm,
                ISNULL(cmam_amortization_start_dt, maxComponent.cm_effective_dt),
                cmam_amortization_end_dt) as decimal(9,2))/12 as decimal(9,2))
            END
        ) AS AmortTermYears,
        tq_dd_product as Product,
        dh_key_rate as KeyRate,
        dh_pv01 as PV01,
        dh_val_time_stamp as RateTimeStamp,
        re_bnk_le.re_company_name as Company,
        rc_contact_id as UserId,
        stp_name as NickName,
        PR.pj_project_name as project,
        '' as Borrower,
        '' as Lender,
        '' as AdditionalInfo,
        CASE WHEN tpm_pd_permission_id = 85 THEN 'LLH' WHEN tpm_pd_permission_id = 86 THEN 'ALM' ELSE '' END as Permission,
        tr_transaction_id as TransactionId,
        NULL as IndicationId

    FROM cfo_transaction TR
    INNER JOIN com_project_transaction_link TL
    ON TR.tr_transaction_id = TL.pt_tr_transaction_id
    INNER JOIN com_project PR
    ON TL.pt_pj_project_id = PR.pj_project_id
```

The query above assumes that every transaction and project is on the table that joins your tables of projects and transactions (thus the `INNER JOIN`), but yo can change those to `LEFT JOIN` if you want

Answer (score 0):

You just add a second join to the other table to the query.

```
select 
    yourfields,
    p.pj_project_name as project
FROM cfo_transaction t
join com_project_transaction_link tl
  on t.tr_transaction_id = tl.pt_tr_transaction_id
join com_project p
  on tl.pt_pj_project_id = p.pj_project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ..., cp.pj_project_name
    FROM cfo_transaction ct
        INNER JOIN com_project_transaction_link cptl
            ON ct.tr_transaction_id = cptl.pt_tr_transaction_id
        INNER JOIN com_project cp
            ON cptl.pt_pj_project_id = cp.pj_project_id
```